# How to Split and Merge Erroneously Segmented Regions

Tags: image-processing, merge, split, image-segmentation, watershed

I have performed the watershed segmentation on a picture of clustered cells. There seems to be many clusters of cells that have not been segmented enough or not at all. There are also single cells that have been oversegmented. What methods could I use to merge the oversegmented single cells and further split the undersegmented clusters of cells?

Edit: The criteria for determining whether a cell has been over or undersegmented will be done by determining whether the area of the cell is within a certain average range of normal sized cells. I'm not sure if this is a good idea though. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Here is a picture of the result if it would help.]
[image]

Comment: The answer should be obvious from this image: there is absolutely no way of guessing where to split and where to merge without any criteria. Randomly maybe ?

Comment: The original image would be really useful to understand the result. In general, if the result is over/under segmented, you have to work on the markers. If you cannot do better, a stochastic watershed is "sometime" the solution.

Comment: it seems your original image was a nice looking structure - can we have that? so you are expecting cells to be some rounded objects or such - thats the  guess

Comment: @ Yves Daoust I have edited the post to explain the criteria I thought of to do this.

Comment: @ FiReTiTi @ gpasch I will upload the original image into the post. Yes I might also use the geometry through central moments to determine a certain acceptable criteria.

Comment: As you can see, the original image was not very nice actually and had to do a lot preprocessing to be able to see all the existing objects of the image. The watershed result is actually a zoomed in crop of the entire picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect to make zero errors and segment everything perfect. Maybe you have smaller or larger cells. Maybe your image quality was really bad.

If you know that cells have an area in a certain range, just adapt the watershed parameters (the threshold) until on average the estimated area is consistent with your prior knowledge.

If you have really large segments (large area, more than twice the average area or so) let the watershed run again locally with a higher threshold.

If you have locally really small segments, let the watershed run again locally with a smaller threshold.

I wouldn't do more except using another algorithm like for example [ilastik](http://ilastik.org/) which has semi-automated segmentation.

Comment: I am aware that a perfect segmentation wouldn't be likely, but the problem is that, erroneous segmentation will interfere with the tracking of the cells. You mentioned adapting the threshold but which threshold are you referring to: the binary threshold or the watershed threshold? Because I wasn't aware that the watershed itself has a threshold.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul If there are more than one threshold you can play with all of them and see what influence they have. Maybe you also want to give other algorithms a try (ilastik for example).

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide what is the ideal or expected cell for you; apparently its some round shape with no reversal of curvature (i.e. it goes around with no reversal of direction) =simple shape. For that you can use  shape features such as circularity: you need to determine what is the  range of circularities that you accept.

For watershed I think it might be better to go for oversegmentation - then shapes that are near can be merged based on whether the combined shape fills the criteria (as above). Other shape features can be used (elongatedness etc).

If you go for undersegmentation you have no choice (under the method you are using) but to repeat the segmentation on the remaining shapes.